# Process.start() odd behavior

Tags: java, c#, dll, process

I am trying to use code to run a popular bitcoin miner.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92716895/DiabloMiner.zip

If you guys know if it, it might be helpful. The thing is that it is a java bitcoin miner. Which needs some dlls to run. The way I manually run it works... which is via cmd going into the directory and typing,

```
DiabloMiner-Windows.exe -u user -p pass -o server
```

But when I use the below code to do the same it doesn't work it gives me `cannot locate java library path lwjgl`.

```
diabloMinerExe = Path.Combine(storageLocation, "DiabloMiner", "DiabloMiner-Windows.exe");
miner = new Process();
miner.StartInfo.FileName = diabloMinerExe;
miner.StartInfo.Arguments = "-u " + this.user + " -p " + this.password + " -o " + this.server;
miner.Start();
```

To clarify...

" It's a C# Project that starts a Process which is a .exe which starts a Java based bitcoin miner. "

Comment: then get the lwjgl libraries...

Comment: have you tried with setting the OutputDirectory where this dll is located<
**miner.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory  = "Dll Directory Path";**

Comment: @Ubica Yeah if you look at the download it has the natives there.

Comment: @RohitPrakash That was not it.

Comment: From where is class Process? What is diabloMinerExe? What does method Start do? Why isn't it called start()?

Comment: @laune Um, I think you are confused at my question. For that I apologize. But the code is in c#. The .exe is given to me in the download.

Comment: @Ubica It's a C# Project that starts a Process which is a .exe which starts a Java based bitcoin miner.

Comment: Do you have `DiabloMiner-Windows.l4j.ini` in the folder? Because I'd say that exe file depends on it, to run java code properly...

Comment: @Ubica The download extracted is exactly what I am running the c# program on.

Comment: are you using `System.Diagnostics.Process`?

Comment: @Ubica I am using precisely that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = "/K java -cp libs\\*;DiabloMiner.jar -Djava.library.path=libs\\natives com.diablominer.DiabloMiner.DiabloMiner -u youruser -p yourpassword -o server";
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

This is a working example... I've made it run. If you need help with it, give me a shout ;)

You will need `libs` folder and `DiabloMiner.jar` in the directory of your C# app

Comment: Tried ,     miner = new Process();
                        miner.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                        miner.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + diabloMinerExe + " -u " + this.user + " -p " + this.password + " -o " + this.server;
                        miner.Start();              No dice.... Same issue library

Comment: It works now. Like that no real clue why but thank you for your continued help throughout this whole thing.

Comment: How about ending the process? process.close and process.closemainwindow don't work when i use process.startinfo.windowstyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

Comment: I would have to look into that, it's been some time since I last programmed in C#

Comment: looked into it and `process.CloseMainWindow();` ends the cmd.exe process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69484/discussion-between-complexity-and-ubica).